# How to retrieve data from db in select?

Tags: php, sql, data-retrieval

In the Year, Month, Day, if input is text, value will show in text, but if its select, value won't show it.

[image]

The problem is in month, it can't retrieve data from table.

Here's my code:

```html
  $tbody[] = $row;
  // Birth Day Section
  $row = Form::label("year", _("Birth Date") . ":");
  $aux = explode("-", ( !empty($formVar["birth_date"]) ) ? $formVar["birth_date"] : '0000-00-00');
  $row .= Form::text("year",
    (intval($aux[0]) != 0) ? intval($aux[0]) : null,
    array('size' => 4)
  );
  $row .= " - ";
  //$array = null;         
  $array['1'] = _("1");
  $array['2'] = _("2");
  $array['3'] = _("3");
  $array['4'] = _("4");
  $array['5'] = _("5");
  $array['6'] = _("6");
  $array['7'] = _("7");
  $array['8'] = _("8");
  $array['9'] = _("9");
  $array['10'] = _("10");
  $array['11'] = _("11");
  $array['12'] = _("12");
  $row .= Form::select("month", $array, $formVar["month"]);
  //unset($array);             
  $row .= " - ";
  $row .= Form::text("day",
    (intval($aux[2]) != 0) ? intval($aux[2]) : null,
    array('size' => 2)
  );
  $row .= " " . _("(yyyy-mm-dd)");
  unset($aux);
  if ($formError["birth_date"] != "")
  {
    $row .= Msg::error($formError["birth_date"]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$row .= Form::select("month", $array, $formVar["month"]);
```

Should that not read...

```
$row .= Form::select("month", $array, (intval($aux[1]) != 0) ? intval($aux[1]) : null);
```

...perhaps?

Comment: If you think this solve your problem, please don't forget to mark as a `correct` answer ;)